# How to use \guilsinglleft and \guilsinglright in csquotes

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

I was reading Jan Tschichold's *The Form of the Book* and he suggest to use

`‹` [\guilsinglleft] and `›` [\guilsinglright]

instead of `« »` for the outer quotation mark. So, I wonder how to do it, provided that Biblatex produces the article entry (and other entries as well) with «guillemots».

The output should look something like this:

> ‹Here is a quote «and a quote within». Done!›

The code should be

> \enquote{Here is a quote \enquote{and a quote within}. Done!}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic interface is pretty simple, but you leave a lot of questions unanswered about the language(s) involved and the degree of complexity about quotations (and possibly about encodings).  Here's the basic idea though:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}  
\usepackage[autostyle=true,english=british,french=quotes]{csquotes}  
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{french}%   
{‹}{›}%    
{«}{»}%      

\begin{document}                       

\enquote{Here is a quote \enquote{and a quote within}. Done!} 

{\selectlanguage{english}%         
 \enquote{Here is a quote \enquote{and a quote within}. Done!}   
}   

\end{document}
```

But see §.8.1 for the many optional arguments for `\DeclareQuoteStyle`, which can take the following form:

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle [ variant ]{ style }[ outer init ][ inner init ]%
  { opening outer mark }[ middle outer mark ]{ closing outer mark }[ kern ]%
  { opening inner mark }[ middle inner mark ]{ closing inner mark }
```